# How can I use IF(bool, a, b) clause in CakePHP's order parameter?

Tags: sql, cakephp

I'm writing a SQL query to order products by price asc, but putting products with 0 price at last.

As I know, I can use `ORDER BY IF(price=0,1,0) ASC, price ASC` to get it done. But when I pass `'order' => array('IF(Product.price=0, 1, 0) ASC', 'Product.price' => 'ASC')` to the paginate component in CakePHP, the `IF` part is dismissed automatically.

I'm wondering how to get it done in CakePHP with CakePHP style param array?

Comment: you can use virtualFields - thats what they are for, after all

Comment: can I add virtualFields on fly?

Comment: yes, that should work - see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Comment: If the virtualField doesn't work, try wrapping in parenthesis like `array('(IF(Product.price=0, 1, 0)) ASC` I've seen that trick work in other places.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want this...

```
if($condition) ? /**want do you want if true/ : /** do what you want if false/;
```

hope it help

Comment: price is not a PHP variable, it's a field in database, so I cannot put it into 'if condition' in PHP.